# Get the list of background jobs from clock.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to get the list of jobs from clock.rb file through controller. I am using ruby 2.3.3,rails 4.2 and clock gem to define the job.

In my clock.rb file my code was

```
module Clockwork
  handler do |job, time|
    Rails.logger.warn "Running #{job}, at #{time}"
  end

  configure do |config|
    config[:logger] = Rails.logger
  end

  def self.job1?
    # ...
  end

  def self.job2?
    # ...
  end
end
```

In my controller how to I get the job list, any idea how to get this done?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get a list of? All jobs what are *defined* in `clock.rb`? All background tasks that are *currently scheduled* (or running)?

Comment: I am trying to get the list of jobs name to display it in the frontend. Background jobs are defined in clock.rb background tasks are scheduled.
I need run the jobs manually from UI. @TomLord

Answer (score 0):

I had to dig a little into [the source code](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork/blob/11f80a0f206d17060b07a55bffec23e935279d1c/lib/clockwork/manager.rb#L65) to find a way of doing this directly:

```
# This is the demo file from the gem's README:

require 'clockwork'
module Clockwork
  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job}"
  end

  every(10.seconds, 'frequent.job')
  every(3.minutes, 'less.frequent.job')
  every(1.hour, 'hourly.job')

  every(1.day, 'midnight.job', :at => '00:00')
end

# Here is a way to then access the defined events:

Clockwork.manager.instance_variable_get('@events').map(&:to_s)
#=> ["frequent.job", "less.frequent.job", "hourly.job", "midnight.job"]
```

Again, looking at the source code, the way this library works is that (for example) when you call `every(period, job_name)`, this [registers an event](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork/blob/11f80a0f206d17060b07a55bffec23e935279d1c/lib/clockwork/manager.rb#L48-L58) in the `Clockwork.manager`.

However, a word of warning: Accessing private data - namely `instance_variable_get('@events')` - is depending on the *internal implementation* of the library. It was not designed to be used this way, and therefore there is a risk that the implementation could completely change in a future version of the gem.

That's not to say "don't do this", but rather, "do this *with caution*". And if you plan to rely on this functionality heavily, consider forking the project (or even submitting a PR?) to make it an official feature of the library.

Comment: Also, note that your "list of background jobs" *may* (?) only be a *subset* of the jobs defined in `clock.rb`. Therefore, consider whether this is really the correct approach you wish to take...